# What does 'against the backdrop of' mean?

Tags: phrase-requests, phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases

How can one use 'against the backdrop of'? Which another word can be used instead of 'against the backdrop of' to mean the same meaning?

Answer (score 3):

Peter's answer is good, using the backdrop figuratively.

Similar to his explanation... if you want to use it more literally:

> The church spire stood out in stark contrast **against the backdrop of** the dark clouds gathering in the distance.

Now, an alternative to *backdrop*:

> The church spire stood out in stark contrast **in front of** the dark clouds gathering in the distance.

Comment: Your example-in-context is an informative and nicely judged nuance that shows up the limitations of my offering. Well done!

Comment: @PeterPoint - I think the two answers together are needed, since backdrop is used both literally and figuratively.

Answer (score 2):

The OP may consider the word **context** as a substitute word for the idiomatic phrase, *against the backdrop*.

**Context:** "The situation in which something exists or happens, and that can help explain it". (Cambridge Dictionary).

Let me give the OP two examples:

We may state that the failure of this year's rice crop has to be seen *against the backdrop* of the excessive monsoon rains that caused wide scale flooding in the rural communities of the country.

Or, we may substitute the word **context** as follows:  The failure of this year's rice crop has to be seen in the *context* of the excessive monsoon rains that caused wide scale flooding in the rural communities of the country.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's a metaphor, derived from theatre.  "Drops", in live theatre, are curtains that can be raised and lowered, and the [backdrop](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backdrop) is the back curtain of the stage.  In many productions it will be decorated somehow, as with an image of rooftops in the Mary Poppins chimney sweep scene.

By analogy, then, dark clouds in the background are a "backdrop" on a stormy evening, or, even more metaphorically, excessively rainy weather is the "backdrop" for a poor harvest.  The backdrop provides a context or sets a mood for the scene.

Comment: Agreed.  On a grander scale, the metaphor can be extended to cover political and social matters.  E.g. "Dr Zhivago is a love-story played against the backdrop of the Russian Revolution."